# AVD Android 4.0+ Não inicia

Tags: android

Quando tento iniciar um AVD com Android 4.0+ no Windows dos meus dois notebooks não funciona, mas com o Linux funciona.

A tela fica preta, não entra nem na tela de abertura do Android mesmo deixando aberto por horas. Nunca consegui fazer funcionar, creio que seja algo que tem que fazer...

Alguma solução?

Comment: Felipe, em vez de usar um AVD, de uma olhada no Genymotion. É uma solução que  abstrai o uso da VirtualBox, com várias configurações de dispositivos e SDK's, e é mais rápida que usar o emulador do Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, Felipe.

Fiz um Breve tutorial de como criar uma partição no AVD.

1º - Sempre Execute o AVD como Administrador do Windows.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º - Clique em **New** para criar uma partição do **Emulador**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3º - Configure-o ao seu Critério, mais recomendo sempre no "**AVD Name**" por a versão do **Android** na qual será selecionado a **API**.

Ex: **4.1.2**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4º - Dê um START no seu **Emulador**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ABS**: Se você tem um Computador potente use o **[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)** Crie sua conta Gratuitamente, é o melhor Emulador na minha opinião, usava ele na empresa onde trabalhava.

Comment: Eu sei como criar... Não era essa a resposta mas vou aceitar pela dica do Genymotion